# MTG: Arena. Is there any way to use packs other than open them?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

I was expecting there to be someway to Draft with the packs I have, but I can't find anyway to do that.

Is there ANYTHING that I can do with packs other than open them and claim the cards.

If not, is there ever any advantage to delaying opening packs? (Any times when packs are more 'efficient' to open? Any advantage to having a surplus of packs etc.)

Comment: One reason (said with light quotation marks) you can't use Arena's packs for drafts is that they contain different amount of cards than the packs used for drafting. I'm sure they could work around this somehow, but they have decided not to.

Comment: I find it more economical to save my ingame currency for a draft instead of buying boosters. I get more cards, I tend to get more rares (since the KI sometimes doesn't pick rares in 2nd and 3rd boosters), and I get at least one additional booster.

Answer (score 3):

No, once you have a pack in your pack inventory on Arena there is nothing to do with it other than opening it.

Arena's packs aren't the same as paper magic draft packs, where draft packs have 15 cards (1 mythic/rare, 3 uncommon, 10 common, 1 basic land (yes you ARE officially supposed to draft the basic lands too)) arena packs contain 8 cards (1 rare, 2 uncommon, 5 common) which are not useful for drafting. Arena does use regular size (excluding basic land slot) draft packs for their limited format games, but you only get these packs when entering one of those sealed or draft events in game.

As for your second question, if there is any advantage to delaying opening packs, yes there is. Arena's system isn't totally random when opening packs, it intentionally reduces giving you more than a playset, this doesn't apply to draft packs which is properly random. This means drafting more first then opening packs later gives you a lower chance of getting unusable duplicates than opening packs and drafting later. The trade off is you have less card inventory for constructed formats while packs are sitting in inventory unopened, so which method is better depends heavily on what formats you prefer.

Arena has two mechanics for dealing with 5th+ copies of cards, something that is very common for heavy drafters who will pick the same good cards often. First, the vault, handles low rarity duplicates, commons give one point, uncommons give 3 points, and for each 1000 points you get to open the vault, awarding 6 wild cards (1mr, 2r, 3uc). The second mechanic handles high rarity cards, and awards gems, 20 for a rare, 40 for a mythic rare.